# iOS 7 background fetch location services

Tags: ios7, push-notification, core-location, multitasking

Does anybody know if you can use the new iOS7 multitasking features, either background fetch or remote notification, to wake up the the app, get the user's location, and send that location to a server? I only want to get a single reading of the user's location not keep location services running indefinitely in the background.

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically you could. The app would already have to have location services enabled by the user.

You could run the location update during a background fetch. The problem with relying on the background fetch, is that you don't know when the actual fetch will take place.

Using remote notifications would give you more control over when the location update runs, but you need the extra infrastructure, and Apple may limit the number of notifications you are sending.

This is all based upon the assumption that you would get through the App Store approval process, which I think is questionable in this particular case. No way to know until you try.